# Mathieu differential equation with $q = -a$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have been trying to solve the equation of motion of a particle in a magnetic field. I was able to reduce the equation of motion to a form similar to Mathieu Differential Equation as:

$$y'' + (a + a\cos(2x))y = 0$$

I have tried to find the solution to the above equation using Mathieu functions. However, i seem to be confused on how to proceed with it.
Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is a [Mathieu equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathieu_function) with $q = -a/2$.

$$y(x) = c_1 \text{C}(a,-a/2,x) + c_2 \text{S}(a,-a/2,x)$$

where $C$ and $S$ are the Mathieu cosine and sine functions.

Comment: can you please comment on how to find C(a,-a/2,x) if a is not an integer.

Comment: Numerical methods or series.
$$ C(a,-a/2,x) = 1-a{x}^{2}+ \left( {\frac {{a}^{2}}{6}}+{\frac {a}{6}} \right) {x}^{4
}+ \left( -{\frac {{a}^{3}}{90}}-{\frac {7\,{a}^{2}}{90}}-{\frac {a}{
45}} \right) {x}^{6}+ \left( {\frac {{a}^{4}}{2520}}+{\frac {11\,{a}^{
3}}{1260}}+{\frac {47\,{a}^{2}}{2520}}+{\frac {a}{630}} \right) {x}^{8
}+\ldots$$

Comment: I don't think it matters whether $a$ is or is not an integer.

Comment: +1 thanks professor!

Comment: +1 @RobertIsrael no it deosent matter...whether a is an integer or not